# insert php values $row into database in another .php file

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table with php values (table.php )retrieve from mysql database.
I want to insert this particular value into another database with the insertion code inside another php file (admin.php)
How should I go about doing it?

Code from table.php

```
<tr>
   <td class="brack_under cell_1">
   <?php    
   $row = mysql_fetch_row($data);
   echo "<a>".$row[2]."</a>";
   ?>
   </td>
   <td class="cell_2">&nbsp;</td>
   <td class="cell_3">&nbsp;</td>
   <td class="cell_4">&nbsp;</td>
   <td class="cell_5">&nbsp;</td>
   <td class="cell_6">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
```

Code from admin.php

```
<?php
   it is something like : $a = $_POST[ $row[2] ]; ???
   $sql="INSERT INTO matchTable (schInitial, schName,position)VALUES
   ('$_POST[ $row[1] ]','$_POST[$row[2] ]','top8')";
   mysql_close($con)
?>
```

Comment: There is no $row nor $_POST in the admin.php. What's the point in all that mess? Why do you want to insert the data into another table and under what condition? how many rows in the HTML table? Do you want to edit the data first?

Comment: the table in table.php displays $row[1] (e.g. "college") . i want to insert this variable into the same database but after i click on a button which runs admin.php where in it has the insert statement. do i have to declare something like $a = $_POST['$row[1]'] inside admin page then can i be able to insert $a into the database?

Comment: without an explanation *why do you need to insert this variable into the same database* it is empty talk. I am not questioning your reasons, but this information is required to give you correct answer.

Comment: okay , i have this tournament table where onload it displays the teams from top8, and after clicking a button , i need to do some algorithm and filter out the top 4 and insert into the database. that is why i need to insert that variable into the same database. but first i have to be able to insert variables into the DB first. (:

Comment: what's the point in having another table? can't you do the same algorithm just at select time whenever you need top8 or top4?

Comment: anyway , i need to pass the variable to another php file so that i can insert into the database , thats it. i think you have misunderstood what i was trying to say

Answer (score 1):

According to the comment discussion and your comments, I'm gonna try to help you a bit here (hopefully I got the point)

You need to POST a `<form ...>` to your script. Unless you do that, there is no `$_POST` available. E.g.:

```
<form method="post" action="myscript.php">
  <input type="hidden" name="some_var" value="player1" />
  <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

This gives the following in myscript.php where you can do your filtering and insertion and stuff.

```
print_r($_POST);
// output: array( 'some_var' => 'player1' );
```

Which means, according to your tries (and to keep it understandable)

```
$a = $_POST['some_var']
// $a is now 'player1'
```

So, the only thing you need to do: create a form beneath your table, put some hidden fields in it with data you need to do your math things, and put a submit button in it.

Comment: so if i have to add php variables into the form , i have to do something like <input type="hidden" name="some_var" value=<?= $row[2] ?> /> is it?

Comment: yup. (but only if you populated `$row` before, of course. and don't forget the quotes, it is `value="[]"` and not `value=[]`)

Comment: yeap i populate them before. my line of code is this    <input type="hidden" name="some_var" value=<?php echo $row2[1]?>  /> , is it correct? when i test the code out , it doesn't print_r my variable out

Comment: like i said, don't forget the quotes. it is `value="<?php echo $row2[1]; ?>"`